# python unbound method must <myMethod> must be called with <MyFrame> instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python

When trying to compile I get the error

```
C:\Temp\pythonWork\superGui>superGui.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\pythonWork\superGui\superGui.py", line 747, in <module>
  MyFrame.disableAll()
  TypeError: unbound method disableAll() must be called with MyFrame instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Code snipet

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    ---- CODE SNIP ----
    def disableAll(self):
        self.btnBeginInstall.Disable()
        self.btnBeginInstall.Disable()
        self.btnInfraSystem.Disable()
        self.btnIwpcSystem.Disable()
        self.btnIwpcSystem.Disable()
        self.btnIwpcIwpcdba.Disable()
        self.btnLdapOc4jadmin.Disable()
        self.btnLdapOrcladmin.Disable()
        self.btnIas_admin.Disable()
        self.btniwpcadmin.Disable()
        self.btnAll.Disable()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    mainFrame = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(mainFrame)
    mainFrame.Show()

    #disable the buttons
    success = MyFrame.disableAll()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I looked at several other similar questions but the answer did not jump out at me, or probably more likely I just did not understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use an instance of that class.

```
mainFrame.disableAll()
```

should do the trick, as indicated in other answers.

Comment: He already has one: `mainFrame.disableAll()` should do the trick

Comment: Thank you very much.  Now I understand why it works.  Because the mainFrame = MyFrame created an instance of MyFrame class... I think.

Answer (score 3):

```
mainFrame.disableAll()
```

instead of

```
MyFrame.disableAll()
```

This should do the job.

Comment: @delhan, thank you! Switching between python & JS code back and force ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it as if it was a class or static method. Where is `self` supposed to come from? You have to call the method on the object that's supposed to do something - i.e. `mainFrame.disableAll()`.

Also, `success` will be `None` because `disableAll` doesn't return anything. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The success = was just an attempt to figure out how it was behaving.  I had a return command in the method but had taken it out, but not the success = part.  Im very new at python and was doing just trial and error.